# Exchange Strings with Numbers in R

Tags: r, string, vector

I was just wondering if R has a way to convert a vector of strings into numbers which I define. For example, say we have a vector as follows:

```
vector <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "ABC", "GHI", "ABC")
```

What I would like to do is rather than having the elements `ABC`, `DEF`, and `GHI` in the vector I would instead like to 'exchange' them with a user-defined number, such that rather than having `ABC` in the vector I have `1`, instead of `DEF` I have `2`, and instead of `GHI` I have `3`, so the vector now becomes

```
vector <- c(1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1)
```

I know that there are functions which do something similar to this, but they don't quite do what I want. For instance, the function `as.numeric(as.factor())` will convert a vector filled with string elements into numbers, which is what I want, but unfortunately it does not allow me to actually define what string value becomes what number, which would be a major problem when the dataset I'm using changes since the numbers would represent different strings.

Another alternative method is using the `chartr(old = "ABC", new = "123", x)` function (where `x` is your dataset) which is also good, but again the major problem behind it is the fact that the number of "old" characters must match the number of "new" characters but also the fact that every instance of a letter will be changed with a number, such that if we replace `ABC` with `123` then every time `B` occurs it will always be replaced with `2` which is not what I want.

Does R have a function which will allow me to swap strings in a vector with user-defined numbers?

EDIT: In particular (for anyone that wishes to do this in the future), I used the following function: `levels(vector)[levels(vector)=="ABC"] <- "1"` This allows you to swap individual string factor levels with a numerical value and vice versa

Comment: use `factor` and specify its `levels`

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thanks, could you put that into a reply so I can accept it as the answer?

Comment: In particular (for anyone that wishes to do this in the future), I used the following function: `levels(vector)[levels(vector)=="ABC"] <- "1"` This allows you to swap individual string factor levels with a numerical value and vice versa

Comment: @ThePlowKing - no need to do it one by one, just: `as.numeric(factor(vector, levels=c("ABC","DEF","GHI")))` should do it. Or `c(9,6,3)[factor(vector, levels=c("ABC","DEF","GHI"))]` if you want totally arbitrary numeric values of your choosing that don't have to be sequential.

Comment: I realise that the first bit of code in my comment above is essentially `as.numeric(factor())` - the difference being that you can rearrange `levels=` to change the order explicitly.

Comment: @thelatemail That's even better! Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1) subscripting** This uses no packages.  Omit `unname` if you want the output to have the original character strings as names.

```
map <- c(ABC = 1, DEF = 2, GHI = 3)
unname(map[vector])
## [1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

**2) strapply**

```
library(gsubfn)
strapply(vector, ".*", list(ABC = 1, DEF = 2, GHI = 3), simplify = TRUE)
## [1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

**3) factor**  This does not involve any packages.

```
as.numeric(format(factor(vector, levels = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), labels = 1:3)))
## [1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

or if the numbers are always 1, 2, ... then it can be simplified to:

```
as.numeric(factor(vector, levels = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI")))
## [1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

If you leave out `levels=` then it will assign the alphabetically first to 1, etc. so if that assignment is OK then it further simplifies to:

```
as.numeric(factor(vector))
## [1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

**4) match** This also uses no packages.

```
c(1, 2, 3)[match(vector, c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"))]
## [1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

If the numbers are always 1, 2, ... then it can be simplified to just:

```
match(vector, c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"))
## [1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

**5) data.frame** This one works with data frames. The first two lines create the data frames, the nxxt line does the lookups and the last line ensures that `m` is in the same order as `DF`.  The last line could be omitted if the order does not matter.  This uses no packages.

```
mapDF <- data.frame(let = c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI"), num = 1:3)
DF <- data.frame(let = vector, order = seq_along(vector))

m <- merge(DF, mapDF, all.x = TRUE, all.y = FALSE)
m[ order(m$order), ]
```

There are several popular data frame oriented packages that could be used here in place of the last two lines above.  The `order` column is not used in these solutions and could be omitted from `DF` for the following.

```
library(dplyr)
DF %>% left_join(mapDF)

library(data.table)
data.table(mapDF)[DF, on = "let"]

library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from DF left join mapDF using (let)")
```

Comment: This is the best answer no question, in particular the first solution works so well and it's just so much more intuitive and straightforward since it doesn't need factor levels etc. Thanks for the very detailed answer and for the huge number of solutions you've given!

Answer (score 0):

```
vector <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "ABC", "GHI", "ABC")
vector
#[1] "ABC" "DEF" "GHI" "ABC" "GHI" "ABC"
vector=as.factor(vector)
vector
#[1] ABC DEF GHI ABC GHI ABC

vector=as.numeric(vector)
vector
#[1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

[Try it Online](http://rextester.com/WBLNW48227)

**Alternative solution:**

Map Strings to user defined numbers

```
    #map strings to numbers
    numbers <- c(1,2,3)
    names <- c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI") 

    #store maping in data frame
    df <- data.frame(names, numbers)
    df

     vector <-as.vector(  c("ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "ABC", "GHI", "ABC"))

     vector2=c() # the numeric vector
     for (i in 1:length(vector)){
     id <= which(df$names == vector[i])
     vector2 <= c(vector2 ,id)
     }
     print(vector2)
     #[1] 1 2 3 1 3 1
```

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/XHHO60173)

Comment: "*as.numeric(as.factor()) ... is what I want, but unfortunately it does not allow me to actually define what string value becomes what number*" - OP specifically states they want something other than this answer.